# any idea about “YarnChild” class not found in hadoop 3.1.1?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am a hadoop beginner . 
I have inastelled Hadoop 3.1.1 on a cluster. As my OS is CentOS 6.9 (64bit), I recompiled Hadoop Native library and replaced it in HADOOP_HOME/lib. 
When I run wordcount example which is in "HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce", I get: "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild". 
I found no answer except changing the version of Hadoop on the internet. 
Any idea about how to solve it? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it is solved.
based on my exprience, any error about class not found is because of mapred-site.xml wrong configuration.
a good config is here:
[hadoop pagerank error when running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599789/hadoop-pagerank-error-when-running)

Comment: Any class under `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` would be the mapred xml, yes. Other class not found exceptions, it widely depends on the application